# How Do I Allow Only Number In a Xamarin.Forms Entry?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making a specialized monetary calculator of sorts using xamarin.forms entries. Since it is a calculator, I'm wanting to only allow numbers, periods, commas, and maybe the dollar sign if it's possible. I'm new to programming in general and tried to follow an example [here](https://doumer.me/xamarin-forms-tips-part-2-numeric-entry-recipes/) of a behavior that would partially do the job. This code seems to be more complex than it would have to be to do a job that seems simple enough and doesn't even do everything I'm wanting to do. I've tried other methods/ways but they are from years ago and appear to no longer work. Here's what I have so far in C#

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CattleCalc
{
    class BehaviorsPage
    {
        public class NumbersOnlyBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
            {


            protected Action<Entry, string> AdditionalCheck;

            protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
            {
                base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

                bindable.TextChanged += TextChanged_Handler;
            }

            protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
            {
                base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            }

            protected virtual void TextChanged_Handler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text = 0.ToString();
                    return;
                }

                double _;
                if (!double.TryParse(e.NewTextValue, out _))
                    ((Entry)sender).Text = e.OldTextValue;
                else
                    AdditionalCheck?.Invoke(((Entry)sender), e.OldTextValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And one entry example from the MainPage.Xaml...

```
        <customentry:MyEntry x:Name="PurchasePriceEntry" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference PurchasePriceStepper}, Path=Value}" Placeholder="1.60" 
                             TextColor="DarkSlateGray" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Ivory" TranslationX="3"
                             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next" VerticalOptions="End" MaxLength="5"
                             TextChanged="PurchasePriceEntry_Completed">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <local:NumbersOnlyBehavior />
            </Entry.Behaviors>            
        </customentry:MyEntry>
```

When I run this, I get a couple errors basically stating that my behavior was not found....Am I even headed in the right direction?? Or is there a simpler way of doing this?? I'm not opposed at all to scrapping this code and going another route if it would be easier/simpler than using behaviors!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are headed in the right direction, there is no easy way to do this apart from a custom renderer, or added behaviour

What you are most likely missing is the appropriate `xmlns` [XAML Namespace Declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml)

```
xmlns:behavior="clr-namespace:<yourNameSpave>;assembly=<YourAssembly"
```

**Complete example**

```
<Page x:Class="WPFApplication1.MainPage"  
    ...
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:SDKSample;assembly=SDKSampleLibrary">  
  ...  
  <custom:ExampleClass/>  
...  
</Page>
```

Just as a side note, i have created one that i commonly use that deals with negative numbers and white space, that might be useful as well.

```
public class NumericValidationBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
   protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
   {
      entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
      base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
   }

   protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
   {
      entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
      base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);
   }

   private static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
   {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue))
      {
         ((Entry)sender).Text = "0";
         return;
      }

      var isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray()
                        .All(char.IsDigit) || (args.NewTextValue.Length > 1 &&  args.NewTextValue.StartsWith("-") ); //Make sure all characters are numbers

      var current = args.NewTextValue;
      current = current.TrimStart('0');

      if (current.Length == 0)
      {
         current = "0";
      }

      ((Entry)sender).Text = isValid ? current : current.Remove(current.Length - 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks! I've fixed the errors...I think and on Android it works(I have the numerical keyboard enabled and can't enter a letter to test) but when I run it with UWP I get an exception of 'The BindableProperty "Behaviors" is readonly'. Why is that?

Comment: @StevenB i am not really sure about that one, maybe thats another question